# SQL - Using 2 where clauses in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to create a result that looks like the following

[image]

The queries for both would be

```
SELECT COUNT(AC) AS QUALIFIED FROM CTE WHERE QUALCODE='QUALIFIED';
SELECT COUNT(AC) AS NONQUALIFIED FROM CTE WHERE QUALCODE='NONQUALIFIED';
```

But how do I use them both in the same query and table?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select count(case when QUALCODE='QUALIFIED' then AC end) as QUALIFIED,
       count(case when QUALCODE='NONQUALIFIED' then AC end) as NONQUALIFIED 
from CTE
```

**Edit:**

> How would introduce a third column where it is the sum of both columns
>   i.e Total 66?

```
select count(case when QUALCODE = 'QUALIFIED' then AC end) as QUALIFIED,
       count(case when QUALCODE = 'NONQUALIFIED' then AC end) as NONQUALIFIED,
       count(case when QUALCODE IN ('QUALIFIED','NONQUALIFIED') then AC end) as QUALIFIED_NONQUALIFIED
from CTE
```

Alternatively, use a derived table:

```
select QUALIFIED, NONQUALIFIED, QUALIFIED + NONQUALIFIED as total_ac
from
(
    select count(case when QUALCODE = 'QUALIFIED' then AC end) as QUALIFIED,
           count(case when QUALCODE = 'NONQUALIFIED' then AC end) as NONQUALIFIED
    from CTE
) dt
```

Comment: This will not skip `NULL` values in `AC` column

Comment: @Prdp, oops, missed that part. Thanks! (Now corrected.)

Comment: Thanks. Just another question. How would introduce a third column where  it is the sum of both columns i.e Total 66?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: @jarlh `count(AC)` will count `QUALCODE` other than `QUALIFIED` & `NONQUALIFIED`also so there could be a mismatch in total count. Derived table method is perfectly fine

Comment: @jarlh - We all make mistakes nothing to be ashamed of  cheers ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use Conditional Aggregate

```
SELECT 
COUNT(case when QUALCODE='QUALIFIED' then AC END ) AS QUALIFIED,
COUNT(case when QUALCODE='NONQUALIFIED' then AC END ) AS NONQUALIFIED 
FROM CTE
```

To get the sum of both columns use this

```
SELECT 
COUNT(case when QUALCODE='QUALIFIED' then AC END ) AS QUALIFIED,
COUNT(case when QUALCODE='NONQUALIFIED' then AC END ) AS NONQUALIFIED,
COUNT(case when QUALCODE in('QUALIFIED','NONQUALIFIED') then AC END ) AS TOTAL,
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

See the code below:

```
SELECT CASE AC
         WHEN AC = 'QUALIFIED' THEN (SELECT Count(AC)
                                     FROM   CTE
                                     WHERE  QUALCODE = 'QUALIFIED')
       END AS 'Qualified',
       CASE AC
         WHEN AC = 'NONQUALIFIED' THEN (SELECT Count(AC)
                                        FROM   CTE
                                        WHERE  QUALCODE = 'NONQUALIFIED')
       END AS 'NONQUALIFIED'
FROM   CTE
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.